# Server dropping every other ping packet

Tags: ping, packet-loss

I'm seeing a very strange behavior one one of my machines, where it looks like every other ping packet is being dropped. Sometimes the evens and sometimes the odds, but very consistently every other packet, e.g.:

```
64 bytes from [IP] ([IP]): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=96.1 ms
64 bytes from [IP] ([IP]): icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=97.0 ms
64 bytes from [IP] ([IP]): icmp_seq=7 ttl=47 time=105 ms
64 bytes from [IP] ([IP]): icmp_seq=11 ttl=47 time=101 ms
64 bytes from [IP] ([IP]): icmp_seq=13 ttl=47 time=104 ms
```

This is from multiple machines across different point and with different network paths and just started recently - I didn't change any config on the machine. What might cause something like this?

Answer (score 1):

This issue turned out to be caused by a misconfigured bond interface on the network path. Originally, the two routers were connected a set of two cables for redundancy, but eventually when more ports were needed, one of the cables was removed, but the bond configuration was not removed on the router side. This was fine as long as there was no cable connected to the former bond port. Unfortunately, somebody was preparing to re-use that port and plugged in a cable. As soon as the link came up, the router started sending every other packet over it (the bond was in `balance-rr` mode), but of course, there was nothing on the remote so the packets would just get lost (for ICMP, retransmitted for TCP).